# Orthogonalize Matrix of Sine Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I would like to orthogonalize the following $N\times N$ matrix whose entries are product of trig functions,
$$
M_{jk} = \sin\bigg(\frac{\pi j k}{N+1}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi j (k+1)}{N+3}\bigg).
$$
My understanding is that in principle one can perform the Graham-Schmidt procedure in order to orthogonalize $M$. While this is easy to do numerically, I would like to obtain the orthogonalized vectors analytically and using Graham-Schmidt does not seem the best way to go about doing so. **My question is**: what are good alternatives to orthogonalize $M$?

*Side Comment*: My motivation for orthogonalizing these vectors is to diagonalize a banded Toeplitz matrix. The eigenvalue equation reads,
$$
a(v_{k+2}+v_{k-2})+v_{k+1}+v_{k-1}=\lambda v_{k}
$$
subject to the boundary conditions $v_{-1}=0,v_{0}=0,v_{N+1}=0$, and $v_{N+2}=0$. $a, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of the eigenvector $v$. The above entries for $M$ satisfy the boundary conditions and I've checked in Mathematica that I once I orthogonalize those vectors they look qualitatively similar to the eigenvectors of this banded Toeplitz matrix.